# Why is the label's text not updating?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

I'm trying to pass data forward from a table view cell button to a view controller. Depending on which row the button is selected in I want the following view controller label's text to be set accordingly. However, when I try to do so, my labels in the following view controller stay blank and don't change. How can I change this?

I added an action to `tipButton` in a table view controller that creates segue to the `KeysController` FYI.

Code for table view cell:

```
class DrillsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var videoURL:[URL] = [URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/RalphSimmonds/Desktop/plainjayne/coolinDB/cook.mov"), URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/RalphSimmonds/Desktop/plainjayne/coolinDB/check.MOV")]
var video = URL(fileURLWithPath: String())
var initialRow = Int()
var firstTips = ["Tip 1: Stay Hydrated", "Tip 1: Keep elbow tucked", "x", "Tip 1: Take quick breaks:", "Tip 1: Keep your head up", "Tip 1: Don't cross your feet", "Tip 1: Don't do more than 15 reps"]

var player: AVPlayer?
var playerController = AVPlayerViewController()

@IBOutlet weak var drillTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var tipButton: UIButton!
@IBAction func tipsButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print(String(initialRow))

    let tipsVC = UIStoryboard(name: "main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "KeysController") as! KeysController
    tipsVC.key1.text = firstTips[initialRow]
}
```

Code for the view controller whose labels I'm trying to update:

```
import UIKit

class KeysController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var topLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var key1: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Comment: Every time you press button from tableViewCell, You're creating new object of viewController and setting label's text. You need to use existing object of viewController for change it's propery(i.e. label)'s value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your outlets aren't wired up until the view loads.

Try creating a property in your KeysController, say:

```
var keyText: String?
```

Set the property after instantiating the view controller:

```
tipsVC.keyText = firstTips[initialRow]
```

Then in your `KeysController.viewDidLoad` method:

```
key1.text = keyText
```

Answer (score 0):

it's because the label key1 is not loaded yet, it's better to update it on viewdidload instead

```
 @IBAction func tipsButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
     print(String(initialRow))

     let tipsVC = UIStoryboard(name: "main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "KeysController") as! KeysController
     tipsVC.key1String = firstTips[initialRow] }




  import UIKit


      class KeysController: UIViewController {
     var key1String:String = ""


     @IBOutlet weak var topLabel: UILabel!
     @IBOutlet weak var key1: UILabel!


     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         key1.text = key1String

     }
```